# “Could not find module ‘Yi’” when launching Yi Editor

Tags: haskell, yi-editor

I successfully installed Yi Editor using Stack (with global setting).

> - OS X El Capitan 10.11.5
> - Stack 1.1.0 (LTS 6.7)

I put the following config file at *~/.config/yi/yi.hs*.

```hs
import Yi
main = putStrLn "It works."
```

Then I ran `yi` and got following error in the “∗∗error∗∗” pane.

```
/Users/kakkun61/.config/yi/yi.hs:1:8:
    Could not find module ‘Yi’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

How can I solve this? And where does Yi Editor find libraries?

P.S. `yi` does not have `-v` option.

```
$ yi -v
yi: unrecognized option `-v'
```

Comment: Answer updated with recipe for stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stack exec yi`. If you want to add options to Yi, use `stack exec -- yi --foo`.

```
$ stack exec yi
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-6.7 from implicit global project's config file: /Users/kakkun61/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Configuration '/Users/kakkun61/.config/yi/yi.hs' changed. Recompiling.
Program reconfiguration successful.
Launching custom binary /Users/kakkun61/.cache/yi/yi-darwin-x86_64

It works.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Stack**

This worked for me with stack:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/yi-editor/yi.git
$ cd yi
$ cabal get Hclip
...create a stack.yaml file...
$ stack build
$ stack exec yi
```

The stack.yaml file consists of:

```
resolver: lts-6.0
packages:
- '.'
- 'Hclip-3.0.0.4'
```

Note: After the `stack build` I tried `stack install` and `stack exec yi` stopped working - so don't run `stack install`.

**Using a Cabal Sandbox**

I was able to install it using a cabal sandbox:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/yi-editor/yi.git
$ cd yi
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
$ cabal install
$ cabal exec yi
```

Modifying `yi.hs` also works:

```
$ cp example-configs/yi-simple.hs ~/.config/yi/yi.hs
$ cabal exec yi
```

To set up a script so you can run yi from any directory, use:

```
#!/bin/sh

YI_DIR=...
env CABAL_SANDBOX_CONFIG=$YI_DIR/cabal.sandbox.config cabal exec yi -- "$@"
```

Here `YI_DIR` is the directory containing the cabal.sandbox.config file.

Note that these instructions are almost the same as the ones found at:

http://yi-editor.github.io/pages/installing/#InstallinginsideaCabalsandbox

except for the way yi is invoked using `cabal exec`.